# Returning value from a callback function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback, graphql, asynccallback

I have a function in this way

```js
function con(){
    database.connect(con, (err, con) => {
        conn.query("select * from person", (err, rs) => {
            console.log(rs)--->result
            return rs
        })
    }
}
var val = con()
console.log(val) // --> Undefined
```

After lot of searching came to know we cant return a value from callback.Done this

```js
function con(fn){
    database.connect(con, (err, con) => {
        conn.query("select * from person", (err, rs) => {
            console.log(rs) // --> result
            fn(rs)
        })
    }
}
var val = con(function(rs) {
    console.log(rs) // --> result
    return rs
})

console.log(val) // --> Again undefined
```

I want to use the rs in another method and should return it in the resolver of the graphql
How to return the value from the above and use it in another function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No i want to again return the value from the con as val it is undefined

Comment: You can't, you'll need to use the value in the callback, or use a Promise like mentioned in the link. `console.log(val)` will run before your `connect` callback function is called, so the only way to know when `val`/`rs` is available is to use a callback/Promise

Answer (score 0):

So, the thing you need to understand clearly -- when you `return`, you return from current function.

In the example:

```js
var val = con(function(rs) {
    console.log(rs) // --> result
    return rs
})
```

you return `rs` from anonymous callback function. But `con` does not return anything.

I would recomend you to use `async/await`, as far as I got you use `pg` or `mysql`.

```js
const connection = await database.connect(connectionOptions)
const result = await connection.query('select * from person')
console.log('Result:', result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i had a callback to the connect and after succesfull connect i need to query the results for query again there is an callback how to convert it to the async await

Comment: @GBulliSwamyReddy, if you want to check for errors on `connection`, or on `query` -- just put them in `try-catch` blocks. That's it. And your code will be more flatter than with callbacks.

Comment: Example: `let connection; try { connection = await database.connect(); } catch (error) {...}`